# Example of BIBO stable system that is not internally stable

Tags: signal-processing, control-theory, stability-theory

In the theory of system, we know that a system can be BIBO stable but not internally stable (if there is a pole-zero cancellation in the transfer function for example). I find this concept quite difficult to understand. So I'm looking for a concrete example of such a system in the real world.

Comment: Real life devices cannot contain infinity within themselves. So *nothing* must be unstable.

Comment: Well take any unstable "real world" system. Add some sensors (outputs) to it that don't measure any of the states which blow up. I must admit though that this is a rather artificial way of generating examples for the kind of system you are interested in.

Comment: @grdgfgr how about an inverted pendulum?

Comment: @Calculon It is clearly unstable. I was saying that you couldn't have intermediate instability and have your system be stable.